# How to use a Server alias for SQL data source in dtsConfig file

Tags: sql, ssis, configuration-files, alias

I used SQL Server Client Network Utility to set up a Server alias for a SQL Server instance configured to use the TCP/IP network library.

In my original dtsConfig file, I have a connection string with the Data Source value which contains the server and instance name(this works):

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[BRADS].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>**Data Source= ServerName\Instance,Port#**;User ID=id;Password=password;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-PackageName-{58F9ABE7-4F56-43BA-AEA2-AD62756E2ADB}ServerName\Instance,Port#;;</ConfiguredValue>
```

When I change the Data Source property to use the Alias, I am receiving a login timeout error(It's unable to locate the instance):

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[BRADS].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>**Data Source= AliasName**;User ID=id;Password=password;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-PackageName-{58F9ABE7-4F56-43BA-AEA2-AD62756E2ADB}ServerName\Instance,Port#;;</ConfiguredValue>
```

I've tried removing the Data Source property and using a Server property, but ot no avail.  Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the above post, I used SQL Server Client Network Utility to set up my server aliases. After checking SQL Server Config Manager, there were 2 nodes for SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration(one being for 32 bit).  The Network Utility defaulted to the 64-bit Configuration.  After adding the aliases to the 32-bit configuration, I am not having any issues.  Thanks!